# Unclear about proper search terms

Tags: terminology

I'm trying to add a feature on my homebrew website that allows users to pin their location to a map.  Ideally, I'd like an email sent that lets me know a user added a location.

I've been searching for an hour or more between Google and Stack, but I don't even know if I'm searching the proper terms.

Any help?  Please.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. We are happy to help and even to fix non-working code, but we aren't going to write the code for you. You should be able to find some Google Maps tutorials online without much trouble, and then please post what code you have, even if it isn't working.

Comment: As the title suggests, I'm looking for the proper terminology that will get me pointed in the correct direction in searching for my solution.  You might try reading the subject first.  "Unclear about proper search terms."

"Oh, what you need is a thingamajig," will suffice.  

Then I'll sift through the code, if any, and deal with the problems from there.

Comment: Actually, just to clear the air, I never asked anyone to "write the code" for me.  Where exactly did you read that?

Comment: You said you wanted a way to pin the location on a map. Try https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation and https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple to start, if that's all you need. Otherwise, maybe be more specific about what you want to accomplish?

Comment: "pin their location" - "email sent that lets me know a user added a location" - "I don't even know if I'm searching the proper terms."

For most people that is extremely specific.  Then there are programmers.

Comment: OK, sorry for implying that you were asking for that, then. It is common for new (to Stack Overflow) users to post code-free questions, expecting someone to "do their homework" as it were.